# Increment Cell Value in Excel but LOOP doesn't behave accordingly

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop a cell value with defined UpperLimit, LowerLimit & Increment with a 3sec interval. But `Do While` Loop doesn't stop ...it keeps on incrementing

```
Sub IntervalIncrement()
varValueL = InputBox("Input LowerBound")
varValueU = InputBox("Input UpperBound")
varValueI = InputBox("Input increment")
ActiveCell.Value = varValueL
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    Do While (ActiveCell.Value < varValueU)
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + varValueI
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: why do you wait twice?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent he's not waiting twice, he's waiting 3 seconds before entering the loop because in his loop he makes 1 increment + 1 wait

Answer (score 1):

It's because your variable `varValueU` is set as a `String` and not as an `Integer` (or a numerical value, more generically).

You should solve the issue by changing this:

```
Do While (ActiveCell.Value < varValueU)
```

... with this:

```
Do While (ActiveCell.Value < CInt(varValueU))
```

**Question 1:**

- Why is `varValueU` defined as a `String`?
- It's actually a `Variant`, since you never declare it, but since you get it via an `InputBox` which has as default type `String` (since you can input whatever) it gets interpreted as a `String`

**Question 2:**

- Why it understands `ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + varValueI` (where `varValueI` is also a `String`) then?
- Because your variables are not declared. It's a very very good habit (actually, in most languages is compulsory) to declare the type of your variables to avoid this kind of issues. If you don't declare, your type will be `Variant`. In your specific case, a `Variant` which is found in an operation (like the sum `ActiveCell.Value + varValueI`) is tried to be evaluated as numeric with success, but it's not the same treatment that the interpreter gives in a comparison (like the condition `ActiveCell.Value < varValueU`)

**Question 3:**

- How do I make sure to declare all my variables and avoid this kind of incidents?
- Add `Option Explicit` on top of your module, the compiler will force you to declare each variable in your code explicitly.

Comment: What's the connection between declaring variables and their types (Question 3)? `Option Explicit` merely makes you declare variable no matter what type of that variable is. `Dim x` satisfies `Option Explicit`. To avoid *this kind of incidents*, you need, in addition to declaring, also set the correct type. The `Variant` is like chameleon - it can contain any type (including `Object`).

Comment: @johnyL yeah, I meant that, probably expressing myself badly